# Selenium Exception when trying to Switch to alert window

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer

I have a Selenium issue. When I clic on a submit button, a confirmation alert is shown. I need to clic on the "OK" button to continue.

The problem is that directly after I clic on the submit button, I have the following exception:

> Modal dialog present

It happens before I try to get the alert window.

```
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", elementInput); // This line throw the exception
IAlert confirmationAlert = _webDriver.SwitchTo().Alert();
confirmationAlert.Accept();
```

StackTrace:

```
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 1341
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 1112
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScriptCommand(String script, String commandName, Object[] args) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 1196
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScript(String script, Object[] args) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 529
   at Kenji.Program.UploadFile(String GTSID, String filePath) in C:\Users\UsrName\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Kenji\Kenji\Program.cs:line 213
```

I use Internet Explorer 17.713.10586.0 and Selenium Dot Net 3.2.0. The application is compatible only with IE.

Many thanks by advance !

Comment: Can't you call `elementInput.Click();` instead of invoking that JavaScript?

Comment: @rene: Unfortunately no, element.Click() doesn't work with IE it seems

Answer (score 0):

You can try accepting the alert using the selenium class Alert to accept the popup instead of using  the javascript

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
alert.accept();
```

Comment: I have the same exception using ExpectedConditions

Comment: the above code should be written immediate after the click event of the web element after which the pop up appears. There shouldn't be any itermediate operation where there might be any visibility check applied to wait for page to load etc

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement();
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(@"{ENTER}");
```

Try this instead of switching to Alert. Assuming the alert is the only active element at that time this should work. Above example is in C#.